# How to programmatically set every other column in a worksheet in Interop

Tags: excel, interop, range, formula

Using Excel Interop (.NET) how can we set programmatically two different Excel formulas for every other column. For instance,

```
Range r = _sheet.get_Range(_sheet.Cells[1, 1], _sheet.Cells[I, J])  
r.Formula = "=something1"
```

will do it for every cell.

But within `J` columns every other column has to have formula `=something2`.

The size of the range is known only at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

First, you create a function to define a range as every other column, a [variant of this](http://excel.bigresource.com/Track-excel-J1w0Pbug/) (VBA):

```
Sub EveryOtherColumn()

   Dim rangeString As String
   Dim columnLetter As String
   Dim i As Long

   Dim firstCol, lastCol As Long
   firstCol = Selection.Column
   lastCol = Selection.Columns.Count + firstCol - 1

   For i = firstCol To lastCol Step 2
     columnLetter = Chr(i + 64)
     rangeString = rangeString & "," & columnLetter & ":" & columnLetter
   Next i

   rangeString = Mid(rangeString, 2)

   Range(rangeString).Select

End Sub
```

Then, you just assign the formula to that Range.